# Generate single exe-file from compiled application

Tags: python, exe, packaging, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I compiled my python-application using cx_freeze, after compiling I got the file "main.exe" - the main application and 28 additional files including DLL library.

Now it looks like this

[image]

Now I need to pack all the files into single exe-file, because if now I run main.exe  from another directory I get an error message, because the DLL library is missing.

What app can help me to assembly all files into one exe-file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know of any tool to create a single runnable exe, but I use cx_Freeze and create an installer with Inno Setup, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Pyinstaller instead of cx_freeze, it gives you the option of `onefile` instead of the package..

with pyinstaller you can just do.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

which will create a single executable with all the modules in it..
i use it several times.

Comment: thanks for answer! But I'm using `Python 3.3`, `Pyinstaller` is not supported this version of python :(